# RegEx in Notepad++ w/Find and replace

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I have data that looks like this:

```
1  ,11/10/2015, 1    3
2  ,01/15/2013
3  ,04/10/2015, 5      5
4  ,04/01/2013, 165
5  ,07/01/2016, 311   312
```

I need to find every instance that looks like lines 1, 3, and 5 and replace the white space in between the 2 sets of digits with a comma so they become like:

```
1  ,11/10/2015, 1,3
2  ,01/15/2013
3  ,04/10/2015, 5,5
4  ,04/01/2013, 165
5  ,07/01/2016, 311,312
```

I'm close with this:

```
[^(^\d{1,3})][[^(\d{1,3})]\s+(\d{1,3})\r
```

, but it's keeping the 2 sets of digits AND the white space.  Need to isolate the finds to just the white space in between the 2 sets of digits.  The leading numbers (1-5) are not in my data set.  Just included these for readability here.

Comment: If this is your input maybe replacing [`\b +\b`](https://regex101.com/r/t2LmUF/1) with `,` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one whitespace-separated digit pair per line, you may use

```
(\d+)\h+(\d+)
```

and replace with `$1,$2`.

If you need to define some more context and make the regex replacement safer, consider

```
,\h*\K(\d+)\h+(\d+)$
```

**Details**:

- `,` - a comma
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\K` - omit all the text matched so far
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `$` - end of line.

[image]

Comment: (\d+)\h+(\d+) appears to do it.  Thank you!

Comment: I just found the requirement *every instance that looks like lines 1, 3, and 5* a bit vague, so the initial regex  I suggest is a bit restrictive. Glad the simplified one also works. I swapped the solutions in my answer.